# How to use class decorator to have read only variable

Tags: python, class, oop, decorator

I would like the variable `next_id` to be read only. I have a hint that it should be achieved using decorator. Any help?

```
next_id = 1

class Product:

    def __init__(self, desc, price, quantity):
        global next_id
        self.__idNo = next_id
        next_id += 1
        self.desc = desc
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

    def get_id(self):
        return self.__idNo

    def get_total_sum(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

tv_samsung = Product('telewizor kolorowy 40 cali', 2499.00, 5)
print(tv_samsung.get_id())
```

Comment: what do you mean by `read only`, how are you going to update it there then?!

Answer (score 1):

Making `next_id` read-only makes no sense in relation to the problem you are solving because you update it every time you create a new instance of the class. And it isn't really possible to do that in Python, anyway. I suspect what you have actually been asked to do is give `Product` a read-only property `id_no` that returns `__idNo`.

Add this to your class definition at the end (and be sure to indent it so that it is actually *inside* the class definition):

```
@property
def id_no(self):
    return self.__idNo
```

Then you can do this:

```
>>> tv_samsung = Product('telewizor kolorowy 40 cali', 2499.00, 5)
>>> tv_samsung.id_no
1
>>> tv_samsung.id_no = 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    tv_samsung.id_no = 6
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you very kindly:)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to assign a value to `next_id` once and then not change it during the code execution.

In other words you want `next_id` to be a constant. In python there is no such a thing as constant. You can reassign any variable you like.

However, there is a convention in python. If you want some variable to be like a constant, name it with upper case letters and just don't change it.

```
...
# Don't change it
NEXT_ID = ...
...
```

In other languages like Java you can create a constant using word `public static final int NEXT_ID = ...`. If you try to change `NEXT_ID` the java compiler will complain about that.